# probability of rolling a die 15

Tags: probability

if you roll a die 15 times, what's the prob that there are four 6's?

Answer is $\binom{15}{4} * (1/6)^4 * (5/6)^{11}$

I am assuming the $(1/6)^4$ comes from the probability you get four 6's, and $(5/6)^{11}$ comes from the probability you don't get four 6's. But what's the point of the 15 choose 4? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there are (15 choose 4) ways to have four 6's.

For example, you have

6 6 6 6 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ (_ implies 1~5)

6 6 6 _ 6 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

6 6 6 _ _ 6 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of ways to arrange the 6's and non-6's.